# Stripe, Angular, and TypeScript won't work together

Tags: angularjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I am trying to do the `Stripe.card.createToken()` which generates a token I should use for my backend. However, I am using Angular and TypeScript, so it all has to play nicely together. I am currently using [angular-stripe](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe) and [stripe.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/36d40a63a05b5cb3413737fbdf7c9a2a26f211fd/stripe/stripe.d.ts) so TypeScript and Angular works. This is currently what I am trying to do, but it does not work:

```
namespace app.Areas.Subscription {
    export class StripePaymentController {
        CreditCard: string;
        Expiry: Array<string>;
        CVC: string;

        stripe: StripeStatic;
        card: StripeTokenData;

        Subscribe() {
            this.card = {
                number: this.CreditCard,
                exp_month: Number(this.Expiry["month"]),
                exp_year: Number(this.Expiry["year"]),
                cvc: this.CVC
            };

            this.stripe.createToken(this.card, this.stripeResponseHandler);
        }

        stripeResponseHandler() {
            console.log("Handled");
        }

    }
    app.controller("StripePaymentController", StripePaymentController);
}
```

When I try this, it tells me:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createToken' of undefined

When I inspect `this.stripe` it says `undefined`. Could this be because I'm not initializing the StripeStatic interface? If so, how do I do it? I really don't know why this isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, okay so I wanted to try something completely different (because TypeScript isn't always working thaaaat well for me), so I changed out `this.stripe.createToken()` with `Stripe.createToken()`. Apparently `Stripe` is of type `StripeStatic`, and now it works fine. Man, 2 minutes after posting here :(